# Getting rid of the list item marker. And the margin

Tags: html, css

I have just a normal HTML `<ol>`

I need to get rid of the number though.

I know you can get rid of it with `list-style-type: none;` but that leaves a huge margin to the left of the item. I need to get rid of them both.

Anyone know how?

Not using a list is not an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you said you want to get rid of margin ... how about:

```
ol, li { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none }
```

if you don't want to reset all margins, you have to at least reset the left margin and padding of the OL and its LIs to get the result you want:

```
ol, li { margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0; list-style-type: none }
```

Note, with a value of 0, the units are not required (ie. 0px). If your goal is to have the items flush left, and I suspect it is, you'll need to reset the padding as well as I've indicated.

As a side note, if you use a CSS reset ( ie: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ ) you'll have to style things explicitly. Not only will you get better cross browser consistency but you'll learn quite a bit too.

Comment: Found where the space was finally. It's the left padding of the `<ol>`. For being the only one to mention padding, you win!

Comment: when you regularly use resets you start to learn what values different elements have by default

Comment: I haven't done anything with lists and css until today. This is literally the first time, so I'm at a loss for some of this stuff. xD

Comment: Really I haven't flat out done anything with lists in general now that I think about it.

Answer (score 1):

A `<li>` has a default margin. You have to overwrite it.

```
li {
    margin-left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
ol {
    list-style-type : none;
    margin : 0px;
}
```

and:

```
li {
    list-style : none;
}
```

Comment: `list-style` is a shorthand for `list-style-type`, `list-style-position` and `list-style-image`

Answer (score 0):

```
ol li
{ 
   list-style-type: none;
   margin-left: 0;
}
```